# Display predicates for all Django Rules permissions?

Tags: python, django, permissions, rules

I am using Django Rules:

https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules

For each permission in django rules permissions, I would like to print the predicates associated with that rule.

Is there a utility to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no function built into django-rules to do what you want, but it's easy to write one yourself.

Rules are stored in RuleSets that are simple dict objects. To inspect the builtin permissions rule set you just need to import it, iterate over it and print each key/value pair. Keys are the permission names and values are the predicates themselves.

Here's some code to get you started:

```
>>> from rules.permissions import permissions
>>> for perm_name, predicate in permissions.items():
...   print("{}: {}".format(perm_name, predicate))
```